# Html link in Highcharts yAxisCategory

Tags: html, highcharts

I would like to add a link near the yAxisCategory,

Is there a way of passing html code to it? I haven't manage to do it

This hasn't worked:

```
yAxisCategory.push(name+'<html><a href="url">link text</a></html>' );
```

Comment: See [demo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) the the API.